# ACF to REST API

Tags: wordpress, api, advanced-custom-fields

I need a proper example of how to edit ACF fields
I'm using 2 different websites one is having the form to submit the data and the other has all ACF fields to be edited.
Where should I verify the wp_nonce?
is it on the ACF fields one or the Form one?
and how can I do it?

Thanx

Comment: Hi welcome to SO... Suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask your question as it stands is off topic. You can update your question by including relevant code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.